# How to display boolean field in prawn pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdf-generation, prawn

I am trying to display a boolean field in a table using pawn. I get the following error:

```
Content type not recognized: false
```

I have read through http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf and the rdoc and can't find the answer.

Here is the simple table layout:

```
  def data
     table [["Design Type", @design.design_type],
            ["Hole Punch", @design.hole_punch]]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you will have the same problem with any kind of variable, not simply boolean.
To get the content of the variable, you need to put it in a string like this :

```
table [["Design Type", "#{@design.design_type}"],
       ["Hole Punch", "#{@design.hole_punch}"]]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just convert the booleans to strings:

```
  def data
     table [["Design Type", @design.design_type.to_s],
            ["Hole Punch", @design.hole_punch.to_s]]
  end
```